# How to align dfs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The first one is like this:

```
 idx  token   tag   file
 0    This    AA    file_1.1         
 1    is      AA    file_1.1
 2    a       AA    file_1.2
```

The second one is like this

```
file          
file_1.1    IXX    GXX
file_1.2    AXX    
file_1.3    AXX
```

How to join the two so that I have the following:

```
 idx  token   tag   file        ID  
 0    This    AA    file_1.1    IXX         
 1    is      AA    file_1.1    GXX
 2    a       AA    file_1.2    AXX
```

So, first I need to align by file column (and I can do this), and then if one line has an id I have to add it to the ID column, if it has more than one, add it to the first token and second one to the second token and so on. I will never have more IDs than token per line.

I tried the following

```
pandas.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,join_axes=[df1.index])
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the columns in the second one? Which column does `IXX` belong to?

Comment: Those are unnamed. If there is something is tabseparated. Most of columns contains only one item. At most I have 6 items per row.

Comment: could you try `df2.columns.values` and post solution

Comment: array([u'0', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6'], dtype=object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I printed out df and df2 so you can confirm that these are the DataFrames you're working with.

```
>>> print df
  token tag      file
0  This  AA  file_1.1
1    is  AA  file_1.1
2     a  AA  file_1.2

>>> print df2
            0     1
file               
file_1.1  IXX   GXX
file_1.2  AXX  None
file_1.3  AXX  None

>>> a = df.set_index(['file', df.groupby('file').cumcount()])
>>> print a
           token tag
file                
file_1.1 0  This  AA
         1    is  AA
file_1.2 0     a  AA

>>> b = df2.stack().to_frame('ID')
>>> print b   
             ID
file           
file_1.1 0  IXX
         1  GXX
file_1.2 0  AXX
file_1.3 0  AXX

>>> c = a.join(b).reset_index(1, drop=True).reset_index()
>>> print c
       file token tag   ID
0  file_1.1  This  AA  IXX
1  file_1.1    is  AA  GXX
2  file_1.2     a  AA  AXX
```

Note that this will be a left join.  You said "I will never have more IDs than token per line.", but in the example, file_1.3 has 1 ID in df2 and 0 tokens in df.  So, I assumed you meant the other way around.  Putting how='right' in the join will do it the other way.

Comment: I didn't know about the stack function. It is exactly what I was looking for. I really really like this solution. Thank you!

Comment: I am experiencing a problem. May I ask you a question via mail?